# Setting precision inline in a return statement for a string function in C++

Tags: c++, string, precision

I have a function that returns a string and I'd like to set the precision of my numbers in the return line. I know this can be done using cout, but I can't seem to make the leap to doing it in a return statement.

For example:

```
std::string dividePrecision2(float a, float b)
{
    float temp = a / b;

    return "Your result with a precision of 2 is " + std::to_string(temp) + '\n';
}
```

If I were to create a string with this like so:

```
std::string str = dividePrecision2(10.0f, 3.0f);
```

The value of that string would be 3.33.

Comment: You can use a `stringstream` as an intermediary that will accept stream manipulators like `setprecision`. You can also use the `fmt` library or, in C++20, `std::format`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I arrived at thanks to the feedback is the following:

```
std::string dividePrecision2(float a, float b)
{
    float temp = a / b;
    
    std::stringstream result;

    result.precision(2);

    result << std::fixed << "Your result with a precision of 2 is " << temp + '\n';

    return result.str();
}
```

Additionally if you have more than a single precision, you can set precision in the stream:

```
result << std::fixed << "x has a precision of 2" << std::setprecision(2) << x << " and y has a precision of 6" << std::setprecision(6) << y << '\n';
```